# How to share data between http and https pages?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

In a content script, I store some data in the localstorage `localStorage.someValue = 1`

But `localStorage.someValue` is not accessible in the https version of the page. Do you have any idea on how to share data between these pages? I would like to store the data page-side and not extension-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot do this, either store your data in the background page storage or use storage api. As possible workaround you could try to inject invisible frame with https version of page to each http webpage and route localStorage values from https frame to main page content script using background page. But this is really ugly solution

Comment: I managed to find a solution using a background page. Thanks for the idea.